# Differences Between Enums in C# and VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, enums

We have legacy character codes that we want to store as numbers in a new system. To increase readibility and general understanding in the code for devs making the migration, I want to do Enums like this...

```
Public Enum Status As Short
    Open = AscW("O")
    Closed = AscW("C")
    Pending = AscW("P")
    EnRoute = AscW("E")
End Enum
```

With this setup, the code will be readable (imagine `If Record.Status = Status.Open`), and yet the values will be stored in the database as small numbers so it will be efficient.  However... I am a VB.NET guy, but everybody wants to code in C#, so I need this sort of structure in C#.

After Googling, I discovered the the general .NET equivalent of `AscW` is `Convert.ToInt32("C")`.  When I try to use that statement in an enum, I get the compiler error "Constant Expression Required".

How can I do this in C#?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A method call is not a constant expression. Try this:

```
public enum Status { 
   Open = 'O',
   Closed = 'C',
   Pending = 'P',
   EnRoute = 'E'
}
```

The reason `AscW` works in VB is that it's an internal thing that VB compiler understands and evaluates at compile time and is considered a constant expression by the compiler. Even in VB, `Convert.ToInt32` will not work.

To quote the [Visual Basic specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=39de1dd0-f775-40bf-a191-09f5a95ef500&displaylang=en):

> #### 11.2 Constant Expressions
>
> A constant expression is an expression whose value can be fully evaluated at compile time. *[...]* The following constructs are permitted in constant expressions:
>
> *[...]*
>
> - The following run-time functions:
>
>   - `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.ChrW`
>   - `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Chr`, if the constant value is between 0 and 128
>   - `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.AscW`, if the constant string is not empty
>   - `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Asc`, if the constant string is not empty

Comment: Well I guess it could not be much easier than this :)  Thank you!

Comment: +1 and accepted, especially because you included *why* my sample code works in VB.  Thank you, Mehrdad.

Comment: It understands AscW because there is an automatic references to the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace in the default projects settings of every Visual Basic project by default which C# does not have. This is used for easy conversion of old VB6 applications.

Comment: Nick: It doesn't really matter that it's declared in `Microsoft.VisualBasic`. The key thing is the compiler is hard-wired to understand `AscW` and it's not really calling any methods at run time. It just replaces the expression with its integral value at compile time.

Comment: +1, It's *slightly* more complicated than that.  AscW is both well understood by the compiler and a feature of the VB runtime.  In the case of a constant and valid expression, the compiler will optimize out the AscW call.  But in cases where it's not constant or not understood, it will defer to the VB runtime.

Comment: @JaredPar: Yeah, of course, if the argument is constant, the value cannot be replaced at compile time. The point is, as you said, the runtime function is irrelevant here. By the way, I don't think it really counts as an "optimization" since the spec clearly requires this behavior.

Comment: I did want to add that I find it somewhat disturbing that I am unable to use string constants like this in VB.  I get the error "Conversion from String to Short cannot occur in a constant expression".  Then I tried a Char literal, that also does not work (similiar message).  I guess it must've been easier to plug the compiler for `AscW` then for literals :D

Comment: @Josh: VB.NET (unlike C#) does not support implicit coercions from character to integers. This design decision makes simply writing "`EnumMember = "A"c` not work. It's not really a matter of ease of implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public enum Status
{
    Open    = 'O',
    Closed  = 'C',
    Pending = 'P',
    EnRoute = 'E'
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I will up-vote this too becuase there was only seconds apart in your answers.  You guys are *fast*!